# Basic Prolog recursion tracing

Tags: prolog

I have the following code:

```
my_length([],0).
my_length([_|L],N) :- my_length(L,N1), N is N1 + 1.
```

Which should essentially count the number of elements in a list.
Here's the trace:

```
Call:my_length([1, 2, 3], _G4652)
 Call:my_length([2, 3], _G4746)
 Call:my_length([3], _G4746)
 Call:my_length([], _G4746)
 Exit:my_length([], 0)
 Call:_G4748 is 0+1
 Exit:1 is 0+1
 Exit:my_length([3], 1)
 Call:_G4751 is 1+1
 Exit:2 is 1+1
 Exit:my_length([2, 3], 2)
 Call:_G4652 is 2+1
 Exit:3 is 2+1
 Exit:my_length([1, 2, 3], 3)
Length = 3
```

Up until here      `Exit:my_length([], 0)` and `Call:_G4748 is 0+1` I understand that Prolog found a fact and that it unified`N1` with `0` and the `N` was made to add 1 to that value.

What I don't understand is what follows after that. Why does Prolog go back to `Exit:my_length([3], 1)`. Specifically, where did `[3]` come from? I'm trying to picture it like going up the call stack but it's not making any sense on how these variables are passed up.

Comment: these variables *are* already in the stack. Prolog doesn't unwind the stack on *exit*. It does on *redo* or *fail*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the trace by pairing a Call or Redo to either an Exit or a Fail. In this case

```
Exit:my_length([3], 1)
```

is paired with the previous

```
Call:my_length([3], _G4746)
```

So this means that the execution of `my_length([3], _G4746)` bound the variable `_G4746` to 1.

A Call is a new record in the stack and a Fail a pop.